# upgrade libc from 2.21 to 2.28 gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf cross compiler

Tags: c++, debian, cross-compiling

I am using `gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf` on my `ubuntu` system using `NetBeans IDE`. My cross compiler is having  `libc-2.21` where as some of the libraries requires `libc-2.28`.And my target machine(debian jessie) do have `libc-2.28` .

How can I upgrade it?

This is the error message I am getting after compiling in `Netbeans`:

```
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libavutil.so.56: undefined reference to 'fcntl64@GLIBC_2.28'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0: undefined reference to 'getrandom@GLIBC_2.25'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libbellesip.so.0: undefined reference to 'fcntl@GLIBC_2.28'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libavcodec.so.58: undefined reference to 'powf@GLIBC_2.27'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0: undefined reference to 'reallocarray@GLIBC_2.26'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libmediastreamer_voip.so.10: undefined reference to 'expf@GLIBC_2.27'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libpulsecommon-12.2.so: undefined reference to 'memfd_create@GLIBC_2.27'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libavcodec.so.58: undefined reference to 'exp2f@GLIBC_2.27'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libavcodec.so.58: undefined reference to 'log2f@GLIBC_2.27'
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/libortp.so.13: undefined reference to 'logf@GLIBC_2.27'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```